# Wordpress custom select query - post ID by both tags

Tags: mysql, wordpress

In Wordpress, I'm trying to run a query to return a postID where it has been tagged by two (both) 'tags'. I think I may need a subquery of some sort. Any help appreciated, here;s what I have so far.

```
SELECT wposts .id
 FROM wp_posts wposts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON(wposts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON(wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON(wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id)
WHERE  wposts.post_status = 'publish' AND wposts.post_type = 'header-image' AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'tags' AND ( wp_terms.name ='homepage' AND wp_terms.name ='position1' )
```

Comment: Please add the RDBMS type as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p .id

FROM wp_posts AS p
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS rel1
    ON p.ID = rel1.object_id
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tax1 
    ON rel1.term_taxonomy_id = tax1.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN wp_terms AS term1 
    ON tax1.term_id = term1.term_id

  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS rel2
    ON p.ID = rel2.object_id
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tax2 
    ON rel2.term_taxonomy_id = tax2.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN wp_terms AS term2 
    ON tax2.term_id = term2.term_id

WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' 
  AND p.post_type = 'header-image' 
  AND tax1.taxonomy = 'tags' 
  AND term1.name ='homepage'
  AND tax2.taxonomy = 'tags'  
  AND term2.name ='position1'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'tag=TAG1+TAG2' );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();        
    the_title();
    the_content();
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

And if you are working directly with the database in WP use this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Not appropriate for what I was trying to do in a plugin, but have an upvote anyway.

Comment: if you can explain what you want too achive, I probably can help you with that